# Why I should pass event to component?

Tags: vue.js

I am learning vue and still can't understand now event system works. In this example I am passing to component `event`:

```
<modal-notifications :aa="isActive" :message="message" @my-event="myEvent"></modal-notifications>
```

That body is discribed in root Vue app:

```
myEvent: function(isActive) {
  this.isActive = isActive
}
```

But what this code is do? It's sending something to component? Or what? Could this code be simplified?

https://jsfiddle.net/tagdjyrL/

Comment: From what I see in this example this is a custom event, which gets triggered when the modal is closed like this `this.$emit('my-event', this.isActive)`.

Comment: But why I should pass it *in* component? Why it's not enough `isActive` that I am passing in compoent?

Comment: Because you have a parent and a child component vue, so with this event you notify the parent when the modal is closed.

Comment: @thefallen, But I thought parent will inform child with `isActive` ?